# Difference in time complexity between storing data as a HashMap and record instance

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity, record

For one of my school assigments, I have to parse [GenBank files](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Sitemap/samplerecord.html) using Java. I have to store and retrieve the content of the files together with the extracted information maintaining the smallest time complexity possible. Is there a difference between using HashMaps or storing the data as records? I know that using HashMaps would be O(1), but the readability and immutability of using records leads me to prefer using them instead. The objects will be stored in an array.

This my approach now

```
public static GenBankRecord parseGenBankFile(File gbFile) throws IOException {
    try (var fileReader = new FileReader(gbFile); var reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        String organism = null;
        List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) break; //Breaking out if file end has been reached

            contentList.add(line);
            
            if (line.startsWith("  ORGANISM  ")) {
                // Organism type found
                organism = line.substring(12);  // Selecting the correct part of the line
            }
        }
        // Loop ended
        var content = String.join("\n", contentList);
        return new GenBankRecord(gbFile.getName(),organism, content);
    }
}
```

with GenBankRecord being the following:

```
record GenBankRecord(String fileName,String organism, String content) {
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return organism;
    }
}
```

Is there a difference between using a record and a HashMap, assuming the keys-value pairs are the same as the fields of the record?

```
String current_organism = gbRecordInstance.organism();
```

and

```
String current_organism = gbHashMap.get("organism");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "storing data as a record instance".  HashMap is a data structure, "record instance" can mean many things... they're not directly comparable.

Comment: What do you mean "time complexity?"  Do you actually mean that, or do you mean time in the sense of wall clock time?  And I see one of your record objects has "db" in the name.  Do you have that code for the records?  And are you talking about the actual access time difference between a hash map and **file** access?

Comment: Records and `HashMap` are apples and oranges -- it doesn't really make sense to compare them.

Comment: I want to save the content of file as a string and group it together with 2 other strings, for them to later be displayed in a GUI. This will be done for multiple files. Would grouping the strings together using a HashMap be faster than grouping them using a record class? I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't clarify.  Seriously.  Write your code first in the most natural way (in **your** opinion).  Think about efficiency issues later.  What you are doing is *premature optimization*.  It is a bad idea.  Inefficient use of >your< time.

Comment: Side note: instead of `try (var fileReader = new FileReader(gbFile); var reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {` you can simply use `try (var reader = Files.newBufferedReader(gbFile.toPath())) {` But since your reading all lines into a list anyway, you could just use `List<String> contentList = Files.readAllLines(gbFile.toPath());`. Then, you have to search for the `"  ORGANISM  "` line in that list, but everything else became obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to store and retrieve the content of the files together with the extracted information maintaining the smallest time complexity possible.

Firstly, I am somewhat doubtful that your teachers actually stated the requirements like that.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to optimize just for time *complexity*.

### Complexity is not efficiency.

Big O complexity is not about the value of the measure (e.g. time taken) itself.  It is actually about how the measure (e.g. time taken) *changes* as some variable gets very large.

For example, `HashMap.get(nameStr)` and `someRecord.name` are **both** `O(1)` complexity.

But they are not equivalent in terms of efficiency.  Using Java 17 `record` types or regular Java classes with named fields will be orders of magnitude *faster* than using a `HashMap`.  (And it will use orders of magnitude less memory.)

Assuming that your objects have a fixed number of named fields, the complexity (i.e how the performance changes with an ever increasing number of fields) is not even a relevant.

### Performance is not everything.

The most differences between `HashMap` and a `record` class are actually in the functionality that they provide:

- A `Map<String, SomeType>` provides an set of name / value pairs where:

  - the number of pairs in the set is not fixed
  - the names are not fixed
  - the types of the values are all instances of `SomeType` or a subtype.
- A `record` (or classic `class`) can be viewed as set of fieldname / value pairs where:

  - the number of pairs is fixed at compile time
  - the field names are fixed at compile time
  - the field types don't have to be subtypes of any single given type.

As @Louis Wasserman commented:

> Records and HashMap are apples and oranges -- it doesn't really make sense to compare them.

So really, you should be choosing between records and hashmaps by comparing the functionality / constraints that they provide versus what your application actually needs.

(The problem description in your question is not clear enough for us to make that judgement.)

Efficiency concerns may be relevant, but it is a secondary concern.  (If the code doesn't meet functional requirements, efficiency is moot.)

### Is Complexity relevant to your assignment?

Well ... maybe yes.  But not in the area that you are looking at.

My reading of the requirements is that one of them is that you be able to retrieve information from your in-memory data structures efficiently.

But so far you have been thinking about storing individual records.  Retrieval implies that you have a collection of records and you have to (efficiently) retrieve a specific record, or maybe a set of records matching some criteria.  So that implies you need to consider the data structure to represent the *collection*.

Suppose you have a collection of `N` records (or whatever) representing (say) `N` organisms:

- If the collection is a `List<SomeRecord>`, you need to iterate the list to find the record for (say) `"cat"`.  That is `O(N)`.
- If the collection is a `HashMap<String, SomeRecord>` keyed by the organism name, you can find the `"cat"` record in `O(1)`.